# Git commit template does not show up when I squash N-commits

Tags: git, squash

I have setup path to the template file on my config file, and it works fine when I do basic commit (`git add -A . && git commit`):

```
[commit]
        template = .git-commit-template.txt
```

---

Instead when I try to squash N-commits, and also add their messages, my commit template does not show up.

=> Is there any way add git template message during squashing last N commits?

---

The way I squash my last 2 commits with the help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/2402577

> If you want to start editing the new commit message with a
>   concatenation of the existing commit messages:
>   `git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"`

```
#!/bin/bash

git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})" # template message does not show up
```

As alternative when I do following I get the same result:

`git reset --hard HEAD~2 && git merge --squash HEAD@{1} && git commit`

Comment: I think you’re pre-populating the message to edit—where would your template even go?

Comment: You don’t see the template because you are specifying that you want the output from `git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1}` instead.

Comment: Even if I do `git commit` template does not show up @matt

Comment: You said “it works fine when I do basic commit”. There is no difference between making a commit before and after a reset. It is still “a basic commit” (whatever that means).

Comment: Sorry if I do: `git reset --hard HEAD~2 && git merge --squash HEAD@{1} && git commit` in order to edit into previous git commit message along the way. @matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-m` argument you have in your sample command *overrides* your template.

You might want to write a small script that:

- reads your template;
- runs the desired `git log` command;
- inserts the `git log` output at some defined template location (perhaps using a syntax of your own invention in the template);
- writes the resulting file somewhere, as a temporary file;
- invokes `git commit --edit -F /path/to/temporary/file` rather than `git commit --edit -m ...`;
- removes the temporary file when `git commit` itself returns;
- exits with the exit status of the `git commit` command.

Note, however, that `git merge --squash` obeys the `merge.log` configuration knob, which might be close to what you want.  You can run `git -c merge.log=20 merge --squash ...`.  The drawback is that this is the `%s` format, not the `%B` format: you get only the subject lines.

Comment: Do I get the subject lines on the git commit section? @torek

Comment: Try it out and see.

Comment: I did `git -c merge.log=20 merge --squash HEAD@{1}` but still having the same output

Comment: You do have to run `git commit` after `git merge --squash`, but when I do that, I actually get a full `git log` of the included commits (not just subject lines as documented). This is with Git 2.24.0, but except for doing a full `git log` rather than just subject lines, this should be the same all the way back to old Git 1.x.

Comment: I do get `git log` results as well but in addition it does not add the git template message, do you able to get the template message? @torek

Comment: I don't use a template. It's not clear how a template would interact with the use of `merge.log`, since Git does not have templates-with-formatting-directives.

Comment: I wanted to see template during the commit of the merge, where I edit my commit message @torek

Comment: A template is a plain text file. It has nothing in it other than the plain text you put in it. You *must* choose: do you want a plain text file with no log in it, or do you want a log? You cannot have both. I also showed you a method by which you can *write a program* that *combines* a template of your choice (in a format of your choice) with `git log` output to produce a *new* plain text file that you can use as a single-use template. **You must write this program yourself.**

Comment: Adding `$(cat .git_commit_template.txt)` solved my problem

Comment: That's a nice simple program. :-) It just sticks your template after (or before) the log messages, depending on where you put it. It's still a *program:* a little bit of shell script. This is why one should learn shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something as follows, where I need to print the template message using `$(cat .git_commit_template.txt)`:

Updated code:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1}) $(cat .git_commit_template.txt)"
git push -f
```